# How did the time drive start up again?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

The recent Agents of SHIELD episode "After, Before" focused on trying to get Yo-Yo's powers back, because her super-speed was needed so that the power core of the malfunctioning time drive could be removed before it caused a disaster.  It ends with her being successful... and then shortly thereafter, the drive goes off again, dragging everyone into the events of the next episode.

This seems a bit odd, given that the component that was removed was explicitly referred to as the drive's power source.  As everyone who's familiar with modern technology knows, if you unplug or remove the batteries from any piece of technology that depends on such a power source, it stops working and can't be started up again without restoring power.  And yet somehow the time drive restarted itself, without any narrative indication that they had replaced the power core.  (Which they presumably had no plans to do without repairing it first, a thing that the next episode clearly shows us has not happened yet!)

Do we have any explanation for how the time drive started up again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems a bit odd, given that the component that was removed was explicitly referred to as the drive's power source.

### Actually, it wasn't.

The part is referred to as the **fuel cell regulator**. so it's not the power source, just a component that manages the flow of power to the drive.

So the drive is still receiving power and *it was just a theory* that removing the regulator would stop the jumps...and we later find out that this is not the case when Enoch says..."it didn't work" and the jump continues.

Comment: Oh, was it?  Somehow I missed that; I thought they said it was the fuel cell.